# can someone tell how to run a function for 1 minute than run another function for a minute in loop

Tags: python, timer

I want to repeatedly execute isCollide in Python for a minute and repeatedly execute
collide for 1 minute. This code will take pictures and check for a black pixel in a specific area
and hit the up key. Thank you

```
import pyautogui
from PIL import ImageGrab
import time
import webbrowser

def hit(key):
    pyautogui.keyDown(key)
    time.sleep(0.05)
    pyautogui.keyUp(key)
    return

def Collide(data):

    for i in range(675, 775):
        for j in range(450, 495):
            if data[i, j] > 100:
                hit("up")
                return
    return

def isCollide(data):

    for i in range(675, 775):
        for j in range(450, 495):
            if data[i, j] < 100:
                hit("up")
                return
    return


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Starting in 5 seconds")
    time.sleep(3)
    webbrowser.open('https://tuckercraig.com/dino/')  # Go to example.com
    time.sleep(1)


    while True:
        image = ImageGrab.grab().convert('L')
        data = image.load()
        isCollide(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

By incorporating a `time.sleep` call in the right place I think we can successfully run `Collide` and `isCollide` more-or-less concurrently using threads. With this implementation, `Collide` and `isCollide` should rapidly take turns running. But as they appear to be very quick-running functions, each should run many times a second.

```py
from threading import Thread


def runner(fn, data):
    """ run function fn repeatedly for 60 seconds passing it argument data """
    t = time.time() + 60 # expiration
    while time.time() < t:
        fn(data) # run the function
        time.sleep(.01) # give the other thread a chance to run

    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Starting in 5 seconds")
    time.sleep(3)
    webbrowser.open('https://tuckercraig.com/dino/')  # Go to example.com
    time.sleep(1)

    image = ImageGrab.grab().convert('L')
    data = image.load()
    # run Collide for 60 seconds
    t1 = Thread(target=runner, args=(Collide, data))
    # run isCollide for 60 seconds
    t2 = Thread(target=runner, args=(isCollide, data))
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    t1.join()
    t2.join()
```

**Update**

Here is an example of how `runner` works:

```py
from threading import Thread
import time


def runner(fn, data):
    """ run function fn repeatedly for 60 seconds passing it argument data """
    t = time.time() + 60 # expiration
    while time.time() < t:
        fn(data) # run the function
        time.sleep(.01) # give the other thread a chance to run

def foo(data):
    print('foo', data)
    time.sleep(5)

def bar(data):
    print('bar', data)
    time.sleep(20)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    data = 'sample data'
    # run foo for 60 seconds
    t1 = Thread(target=runner, args=(foo, data))
    # run bar for 60 seconds
    t2 = Thread(target=runner, args=(bar, data))
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    t1.join()
    t2.join()
```

Prints:

```
foo sample data
bar sample data
foo sample data
foo sample data
foo sample data
bar sample data
foo sample data
foo sample data
foo sample data
foo sample data
bar sample data
foo sample data
foo sample data
foo sample data
foo sample data
```

Comment: I've updated the answer with a demo of how it is *supposed* to work and how it does work for me. Can you be more descriptive than "It didn't work for me"?